# Drawing Arrow between two points in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, graphics

I am dynamically generating an image in ASP.NET. How can I draw an arrow instead of the line in the below code snippet. I couldn't find any API for this.

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(640, 480);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
.
.
graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), lPoint, rPoint);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(640, 480);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 10);
p.EndCap = LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
graphics.DrawLine(p, lPoint, rPoint);
```

See [LineCap Enumeration MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.linecap.aspx)